# How to install the cube function for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

when I just run the sample statements like below:

```
select cube_union('(0,5,2),(2,3,1)', '0')
```

but facing the error:

```
postgres=# select cube_union('(0,5,2),(2,3,1)', '0');
ERROR:  function cube_union(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select cube_union('(0,5,2),(2,3,1)', '0');
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
postgres=#
```

Can anyone help me? Is there any place I need to setup or need to install the function separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `cube_union()` function is provided by the extension [cube](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/cube.html)

To install an extension you need [create extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html)

An extension is installed per database, so you need to connect to the database you are using as a super user, then run:

```
create extension cube;
```